# How to reset Buffalo LinkStation password without erasing data?

Tags: reset, buffalo-nas

Sadly my IT Admin suddenly passed away :( Unfortunately he did not take very good notes so now we don't know what our Buffalo LinkStation's admin user and password is.

How can I reset the password without deleting the data inside?

Comment: read or find the manual online.  resetting to factory settings might not erase the data.

Comment: According to some buffalo forum, resetting the Buffalo Linkstation will not erase your data, but will erase your system setting (IP address, username/password, other system configuration) to default. If you are not convinced, do contact Buffalo support directly and they can give a much more definite answer.